# Sending files via bluetooth

Tags: release-loki, bluetooth

I'm not sure, if I am just stupid, or discovered a bug. I wanted to send a file to my phone, using bluetooth.

I did the pairing, and then wanted to send a file: [image: Bluetooth settings]

Then comes the file selection dialog, where I selected the file:[image]

But from there, I did not know, what to do. There is no **send file** button, hitting `enter` does nothing, and the window does not even have a close button. To close it, I had to use the dock. But it did not send the file :(

Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Comment: You better try `Superbeam`.  You can check here for more about it. You can transfer files faster than bluetooth.  http://www.kvcodes.com/2016/09/install-superbeam-ubuntu-lubuntu-elementary-os-kubuntu/

Comment: Yes, it is a bug. I have suffered it when I try playing music, even though the bluetooh in panel looks connected. I have to repeat the process two times at least. In the end it works. My english is bad, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is a bug, you might want to report it https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+filebug

Comment: I did this. Anyone interested can find the [report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1629240)